# Using Manipulate[] to manipulate Plot[] min and max values

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate, visualization, algebra

I have code:

```
Plot[y = -3*x + 2, {x, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}]
```

output:

[image]

Now I want to use `Manipulate[]` to manipulate values of this part `{x, -10, 10}` of the code presented above.

I used different variants like:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[y = -3*x + 2, {x, fr1, fr2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}], {fr1, -10, 10}, {fr2, -10, 
  10}]
```

without any lack.

**Question:** How to use `Manipulate[]` to manipulate values of this part `{x, -10, 10}` of my first code? I mean manipulate min and max values of `x` on the plot.

Comment: If you change `fr2` to `{fr2, 10}` (i.e., set an initial value for that symbol) it will work.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit This `Manipulate[
 Plot[y = -3*x + 2, {x, {fr1, 10}, {fr2, 10}}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}], {fr1, -10, 10}, {fr2, -10, 10}` or this `Manipulate[
 Plot[y = -3*x + 2, {x, fr1, {fr2, 10}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}], {fr1, -10, 10}, {fr2, -10, 10}` does not works. Can you please post corrected whole code?

Comment: I should've been clearer. You should leave the 1st argument of `Manipulate` unchanged (i.e., everything inside `Plot`). You need to change `{fr2, -10, 10}` to `{{fr2, 10}, -10, 10}` in the last argument of Manipulate.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit That works. Thank you. Complete code: `Manipulate[
 Plot[y = -3*x + 2, {x, fr1, fr2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}], {fr1, -10, 
  10}, {{fr2, 10}, -10, 10}]`

Comment: Final remark: there's no good reason to use `y = ...` inside of `Plot`. Just `Plot[3*x + 2, {x, fr1, fr2}, ...]` will suffice.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thank you. Your remarks are very valuable for me. So with `y = ...` I am creating unnecessary variable `y` by first assigning expression to it and after passing that variable to command. Instead I should directly pass expression to command. Is it correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106166/discussion-between-sjoerd-smit-and-vasili111).

Answer (score 5):

One way could be

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{y, x},
  Plot[y = -3*x + 2, {x, from, to},
   AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   PlotRange -> {{from, to}, {from, to}}]
  ],
 {{from, -10, "from"}, -10, -0.01, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{to, 10, "to"}, 0, 10, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {from, to}
 ]
```

[image]

If you meant the `from`  and `to` only for the `x` part and not for the `plotrange`, then you use this

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{y, x},
  Plot[y = -3*x + 2, {x, from, to},
   AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}]
  ],
 {{from, -10, "from"}, -10, -0.01, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{to, 10, "to"}, 0, 10, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {from, to}
 ]
```

You just need to make sure the `from` is not larger than the `to`, that is all, else `Plot` complains.

And if you do not want to worry about `from` being larger than `to`, then you can add a small check in the code to check for this and adjust automatically, so `Plot` stays happy.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{y, x},

  (*prevent from from going above to to keep plot happy*)
  If[from >= to, from = to - 0.01];

  Plot[y = -3*x + 2, {x, from, to},
   AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}]
  ],
 {{from, -10, "from"}, -10, 10, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{to, 10, "to"}, -10, 10, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {from, to}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting example. Thank you. Is there a way to manipulate not on plot range but on value of `x` ? I mean plot is fixed and min and max values of x changes with sliders.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) to make the input function `Undefined` outside the desired interval and use [`IntervalSlider`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalSlider.html) to specify the interval:

```
Manipulate[Plot[ConditionalExpression[-3*x + 2, r[[1]] <= x <= r[[2]]], {x, -10, 10}, 
    GridLines -> {r, None}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}],
 Panel[Row[{Dynamic @ Pane[r[[1]], Alignment -> Right, ImageSize -> {50, 20}], 
     IntervalSlider[Dynamic[r], {-10, 10}, Method -> "Stop", 
       Appearance -> "Paired", ImageSize -> 300], 
     Dynamic @ Pane[r[[2]], Alignment -> Left, ImageSize -> {50, 20}]}, Spacer[10]], 
    Style["x range", 16], Top], 
 {{r, {-10, 10}, ""}, None}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`Clip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html)ped `x` values as the argument of the input function:

```
Manipulate[Plot[-3 Clip[x, r, {Undefined, Undefined}] + 2, {x, -10, 10}, 
    GridLines -> {r, None}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}],
 Panel[Row[{Dynamic @ Pane[r[[1]], Alignment -> Right, ImageSize -> {50, 20}], 
     IntervalSlider[Dynamic[r], {-10, 10}, Method -> "Stop", 
       Appearance -> "Paired", ImageSize -> 300], 
     Dynamic @ Pane[r[[2]], Alignment -> Left, ImageSize -> {50, 20}]}, Spacer[10]], 
    Style["x range", 16], Top], 
 {{r, {-10, 10}, ""}, None}]
```

[image]